# Cannot determine how to use JSON.net in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, json.net

I installed JSON.net using Nuget and it says it's installed into my Visual Studio project. I see a reference in the references section.

In Javascript, I want to serialize an array, but when I begin to type in JsonConvert, the only thing intellisense shows is JSON.

Apparently, I need to do something so it's available in Javascrip0t, but for the life of me, I can't determine what. I looked to see about including a script reference in the header, but I can't find any .js files. So, I'm at a loss.

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.Net is for C# or VB at the server, not the client.

There should be JSON.parse and JSON.stringify at the client (most browsers have them).

Comment: Ah, that explain it. My reason for installing is because I'm getting an error stating "JavaScript runtime error: 'json' is undefined" when I try to use JSON.Stringify. Everywhere I searched says to use <!DOCTYPE html> in the page, which I am doing. So, I'm at a loss. I'm using IE11. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveM Javascript is case sensitive.  Are you typing "json" or "JSON"?